# Saving and reusing tag definition in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, refactoring, code-reuse

Let's say I have the following construct polluting the simplicity of my JSF code in many places:

```
<p:calendar id="decisionDate"
    effect="explode" 
    yearRange="2000:2100"
    pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
    navigator="true" display="inline"
    value=""
    label="Decision Date"
    maxlength="10"
    size="20">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</p:calendar>
```

As can be seen, this has nine (9) attributes and a nested tag.  This is an awful amount of tedious detail to consume with your eye.

Is there a way I can reuse `PrimeFaces` tags in a similar way as `CSS`:  to save a complex tag definition as `<px:myCalendar/>` with the above parameters minus the ID ones, which should be set for each instance of use nonetheless, where `px` would be my namespace and then each time I need to invoke it, I would just say `<px:myCalendar id="uniqueCalID"/>` and ...  BOOM ... there goes all the repeated clutter?

**POST ANSWER EDIT:**  Check out [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define composite component. It is defined with xhtml+ jsf namespaces and, but in your case it is unnesessary, backing component, which is java class, instantiated for every composite component usage.

Within composite component interface you can define attributes, which vary its behaviour. And in implementation you then can insert needed primefaces' component with some hardcoded attributes and some passed from your composite component invocation.

Consider this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html

**Example**

Composite component is resource, so we put it below `/resources` folder. Let's create subfolder `/resources/myCompositeComponents` and create xhtml file `myCalendar.xhtml` there. It will be our composite component. Basically, it is xhtml file with additional namespace `xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"`. Here is the code. You can notice two elements: `<cc:interface>` and `<cc:implementation>`. And `<cc:attribute>` element inside the `<cc:interface>`  is the input of our composite component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="label" default="Decision Date"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h2>#{cc.clientId}</h2>
    <h:outputLabel
            id="Label"
            value="#{cc.attrs.label}"/>
    <p:calendar id="Calendar"
                effect="explode"
                yearRange="2000:2100"
                pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
                navigator="true" display="inline"
                value=""
                label="Label"
                maxlength="10"
                size="20">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
    </p:calendar>
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

Then, let's use it. To be able to declare our brand new component we will put additional namespace into the using page: `xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/myCompositeComponents"`. The last part of the namespace uri corresponds to the folder under `/resources`, where composite component lives. Give it any prefix you like. Here is source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/myCompositeComponents">

<h:head>
    <title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <my:myCalendar id="LetsUseIt" label="MyLabel"/>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Have a notice of attribute "label" - that very attribute, that is declared in the "interface" element.

This is quite basic usecase, though it will help in your situation. More complex scenarios include passing typed attributes and implementing backing component - java class, instantiated every time the component is used.

Comment: thanks.  do you know if there is a way to concentrate all the repeated/constant attributes in the composite but put the variable one(s) in the final implementation, like I exemplified above with `id`?

Comment: Yes, there is. When I get to my PC, I'll remaster your example with composite component. In short, in cc:interface section you declare component type, which will serve as tag name for this component in the using page. Also, you declare some attributes with cc:attribute and set their name, type, whether attibute is required or not, default value. Through these attributes using page passes variable parameters to the component. Id attribute has special meaning. You should not declare it in the interface, it can be accessed with #{cc.clientId} EL expression.

Comment: thanks.  also, if you could provide an actual small example, that would be great

Comment: thanks.  however, what confuses me is "And attribute element inside the interface is the input of our composite component."  I don't quite get that from your otherwise great exhibit.  can you explain how that works?

Comment: I mean element <cc:attribute name="label"> inside <cc:interface>. It declares that your component will accept attribute "label" when used in some page: <my:myCalendar label="something">.

Comment: It's worth noting that composite components are not specific to Primefaces only - they are part of JavaServer Faces 2.x specification.